# Is there a way to pass treeViewItem name as command parameter?

Tags: c#, xaml, treeview

I am creating a simple treeview with binding to a collection. What I want is to display full info about the collection element in a listview when treeview element is selected. Similar to windows file explorer. The problem is I cannot bind selected treeviewitem to a Command.

Tried binding command to SelectedItemChanged event with a parameter of treeviewitem name - didn`t work.
Tried it with a simple event - gets cumbersome and breaks MVVM pattern. There must be an elegant way to solve this since what I am trying to do is really widespread in different apps.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Background="AliceBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding TopPanelNodes}" Name="TopTreeView" SourceUpdated="TopTreeView_SourceUpdated" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" IsEnabled="False">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" >
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateInspectorCommand }" CommandParameter=???                                                    />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>                        
</TreeView>
```

I would like to pass treeviewitem name as command parameter instead of ??? in my code so selected treeview item will be identified by name so I can get respective info and bind it to listview.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using RelativeSource.

CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"

Works fine.